# Saving Data to a txt file with a runnable jar

Tags: jar, save, runnable

---

Hello,

I can't find out how to make it so i can save data to a txt. It works while I'm in eclipse but not when i export as a runnable Jar File.

My code is:

```
public void openFile()
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "src/save/Kube.txt");
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    x = new BufferedWriter(fw);

}

public void addRecords() {
    try {
        x.write(game.getTotalCoins() + "\n");
        x.write(game.getHighScore() + "\n");
        x.write(game.getBackround() + "\n");
        x.write(game.getCube() + "\n");
        x.write(game.isBlackselected() + "\n");
        x.write(game.isBlueselected() + "\n");
        x.write(game.isGreenselected() + "\n");
        x.write(game.isBlueunlocked() + "\n");
        x.write(game.isGreenunlocked() + "\n");
        x.write(game.isDefaultselected() + "\n");
        x.write(game.isSkyselected() + "\n");
        x.write(game.isUnderwaterselected() + "\n");
        x.write(game.isSkyunlocked() + "\n");
        x.write(game.isUnderwaterunlocked() + "");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void closeFile() {
    try {
        x.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When ran in eclipse it works fine but when made into runnable jar file does not save.
Thanks for your help!